# DB design for utility bills

Tags: mysql, database-design

In a system I need to save data for some different utility bills for electricity, water, recycling in order to make reports and calucations in the future.

Today each utility bill comes with several different posts/rows. For instance `electricity` bill can include `fixed fee` (amount for the daterange of the bill) `consumption` (usually billed per kWh for electricity, m3 for water etc) `taxes` (could be energy taxes)

As I want to be able to use the database later to search the data for various time periods, utility bill types etc I need to come up with a solid db design. So the below would be my start.

```
`utility_bill`
  `id` int(11)
  `vendor_id` int(11)
  `type_id` int(11)
  `notes` varchar(255)
  `date_issued` date
  `date_due` date

`utility_bill_rows`
  `id` int(11)
  `utility_bill_id` int(11)
  `name` varchar(64)
  `startdate` date
  `enddate` date
  `units` double
  `unit_price` double
  `unity_type` varchar(16)
```

Example of data:

```
`utility_bill`
1   2   2   Electricty bill (august)    2016-09-01  2016-09-30

`utility_bill_rows`
1   1   Fixed fee   2016-08-01  2016-08-31  31  10  days
2   1   Consumption 2016-08-01  2016-08-31  500 1   kwh
3   1   Government taxes    2016-08-01  2016-08-31  500 0.1 kwh
```

In above example `bill_total` would be `310 + 500 + 50 = 860`

Not all utility bills are based on monthly cycles. In some cases it could be `2016-07-01 to 2016-09-30`, `2016-08-15 to 2016-09-15` and so on. Hence I was thinking about adding a new column to table `utility_bill_rows` called `daily_cost` which would simply be `(units * unit_price) / (enddate - startdate in days)`.

So any suggestions to the above design and thoughts are much appreciated. Should I make some additions to the design that might be useful later when

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have a question? Asking for opinions or ideas is not what we do on SO....

Comment: As mentioned at the bottom. Should I make changes in order to be able to extract the data in the future. Should I save data based on daily cost as well or is that a bad approach.

Comment: Adding computable columns is normally frowned on in database design.  But this is a tiny table; treat it as a learning experience.  Add the column to see how it feels.  Then write the `SELECTs` as if the column weren't there.  That way, you experience both.

Comment: @MartinBean: But there's no code here to review.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Suppose you wanted to total all the taxes charged during a particular time. You would have `where name = "Government taxes" in the query. That's not very robust and just awkward.

Try putting these categories in a separate lookup table named, oh, `billedUnits`:

```
ID  Name        Other_info
 1  Fixed fee   ...
 2  Consumption ...
 3  Taxes       ...  -- "Government" is a duplicative redundancy
```

Then, instead of the field `name` in `utility_bill_rows`, use `billedUnitID` and use the ID value of the lookup table. This also makes it easier to add new categories like "Solar surcharge".

The most significant improvement would be to add a `term` field in `utility_bill` table. This can be a single-character designator like 'M' for monthly and 'Q' for quarterly or a small integer like 30 and 90 for the days of the term. This would greatly simplify queries that concern only monthly bills or only quarterly bills. I lean a little to the integer as that would also simplify the per-day calculation.

You can add a `daily_cost` field if the contents of the row are stable -- that is, if once written the values rarely if ever change. If there are relatively frequent adjustments, don't bother, just recalculate when needed.

Also, be aware of the concepts "cost" and "charge". At your end, all these values are charges. It is your customer who sees costs. So if you do create this field, a better name would be `daily_charge`.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. Actually I did some changes and moved startdate and enddate to just be in `utility_bill` and added `term` to that table as well.

In regards to `billedUnits` you think it would be a good idea to use same  `consumtion` for all utitlity types such as water, elecricity etc or should I keep them separated? I can still see what type by looking at `type_id` in `utility_bill`

Comment: As it would be highly unlikely you would ever be looking at the `utility_bill_rows` data without first having read from `utility_bill`, there is no need to duplicate any data to the row.